# Hibernate 6 Instant always uses UTC? - does not need jdbc.time_zone setting

Tags: java, mysql, hibernate

I know about the `jdbc.time_zone = UTC` setting from [Vlad Mihalcea](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1025118/vlad-mihalcea)'s article:

https://vladmihalcea.com/how-to-store-date-time-and-timestamps-in-utc-time-zone-with-jdbc-and-hibernate/

so that Hibernate will persist java.time.* objects in UTC. In practice Instant always seems to use UTC regardless of this setting (which I guess makes sense).

I couldn't find this documented anywhere though. So I just wanted to get confirmation that Instant will be always be persisted/retrieved as UTC, regardless of the `jdbc.time_zone` setting. Has this always been the case since Hibernate 5.2 when `jdbc_time_zone` was introduced?

In case it matters: in this particular case the target column is a MySQL 8 DATETIME(3), the connector is mysql-connector-jar:8.0.33, and Hibernate is 6.2.x.

With logging turned on

```
... other stuff ...
21:15:15.282 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [4] as [TIMESTAMP_UTC] - [2023-08-11T13:15:15.244980506Z]
21:15:15.282 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [5] as [TIMESTAMP_UTC] - [2023-08-18T13:15:15.189442027Z]
21:15:15.282 [main] TRACE org.hibernate.orm.jdbc.bind - binding parameter [6] as [TIMESTAMP_UTC] - [2023-08-11T13:15:15.244980506Z]
... other stuff ...
```

Comment: By definition, the `java.time.Instant` class *always* represents a moment as seen in UTC, an offset of zero hours-minutes-seconds from UTC.

Comment: You are using the **wrong data type** in MySQL. To track a moment, a specific point on the timeline, in MySQL, use the type `TIMESTAMP`. You are using `DATETIME` which tracks a date and time-of-day but lacks the context of a time zone or offset. Transferring a MySQL `DATETIME` value to/from a Java `Instant` value makes no sense. The equivalent of MySQL `DATETIME` in Java is `java.time.LocalDateTime`. See [doc](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/datetime.html).

Comment: @BasilBourque - a Java java.time.* mapping to TIMESTAMP column has some undesirable MySQL automatic timezone conversions where we don't have control over the database timezone. Also we try to keep the existing JDBC URL - which doesn't set the timezone.

Comment: No, in JDBC 4.2 and later, the MySQL type `TIMESTAMP` maps to `java.time.OffsetDateTime`. The default time zone of your database server, of your database session, and of your JVM are all irrelevant. If you cannot get that to work, you should post a Question on *that* topic. Your Question here is nonsensical, per my second Comment.